# Forcing a trailing slash at the end of the URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I currently have this on my htaccess file to map mydomain.com/contact-us -> mydomain.com/contact-us.php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^contact-us(\/?)$ /contact-us.php [NC,QSA,L]
```

My problem is I want it ALWAYS to show a `/` at the end of the URL even if the users did not typed it, currently both with or without slash it will map to mydomain.com/contact-us.php

Comment: 'I want it ALWAYS to show a /'. Why? The meaning is the same with or without.

Comment: Im afraid that SE might view that as duplicate contents one without / and the other one is with /

Comment: Do you have any basis for that fear? Search engines are bound by the rules of HTTP too.

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect requests to the page without a slash to the page with a slash with a permanent redirect:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^contact-us$ /contact-us/ [R=301,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^contact-us/$ /contact-us.php [NC,QSA,L]
```